# In phonegap I cant select from a database if I am coming from a form click

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to find out how many rows are in a database. I want to know if the database already has an item in it or not. I am able to create a button that will go to the database and do the gotLog3 function call with the result with no problem.

```
$("#countButton").click(function(e){
    teacherInfo.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select * from logTeacherInfo",[],gotLog3,errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler, function() {});
});
```

Now if I try to submit a form and do the same check it will not call the gotLog3.

```
$(".button").click(function() { 
teacherInfo.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select * from logTeacherInfo",[], gotLog3,errorHandler);
}, errorHandler, function() {});
});
```

These hunks of code are right next to each other. One works the other does not. Any ideas why?

Comment: This can possibly happen because of the form submit action, submit can empty the controls and the values in variables. Please check if that's the cause.

Comment: Nothing seems to be lost when I hit the submit button. It just does not call the gotLog3 function. If I hit the countButton it does call the gotLog3 function. What do you mean it can empty the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if you use a type "button" instead of a type "submit" on your html form it will call the function gotLog3. I am unsure why this is though.